# How to control vlc from python with m1 mac?

Tags: python, vlc

I tried to run 'import vlc' in a python script, but got this error-

> OSError:
> dlopen(/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libvlccore.dylib,
> 0x0006): tried:
> '/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libvlccore.dylib' (mach-o
> file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need
> 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/libvlccore.dylib' (no such file),
> '/usr/lib/libvlccore.dylib' (no such file),
> '/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libvlccore.9.dylib' (mach-o
> file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need
> 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/libvlccore.9.dylib' (no such file),
> '/usr/lib/libvlccore.9.dylib' (no such file)

Is it possible to run vlc from python on the new macs?